# two network card, which card 127.0.0.1 represent?

Tags: localhost

If there is one network card, we can access this card's corresponding port through 127.0.0.1:port. But if there are two network cards and they are monitoring the same port(such as 6000), which card will be accessed when I access 127.0.0.1:6000? If you think they are independent, what relation between them? I think there must be some relation between them, because "If there is one network card, we can access this card's corresponding port through 127.0.0.1:port.".

Comment: 127.0.0.1 represent itself only, it is completely independent to the other two network card address.  The fact is that my socket has listened "INADDR_ANY", this indicate to listen any address of this host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of them. 127.0.0.1 is the loopback interface. It exists even if you don't have network cards.
The network cards will have their own different ip address.

On Un*x systems you can list your netowrk intrfaces with *ifconfig -a*

On Windows you can do the same with *ipconfig /all*

Comment: I think there must be some relation between them, because "If there is one network card, we can access this card's corresponding port through 127.0.0.1:port.".

Comment: I don't know where you got that from but it is wrong. If you are logged in to the computer that has the physical card, and the server program you want to access is running on that computer, and it is bound to both, the loopback interface and to the network card on the same port, you can connect to the server (from that same computer) using either the loopback or the network card address and port. But stil they are different interfaces not one interface you can reach from different ip addresses.

Comment: You are right, the fact is that my socket has listened "INADDR_ANY", this indicate to listen any address of this host.  Thanks very much!